# Verifying checksum in IP Packet in python

Tags: python, checksum, packet

I need to verify the checksum header of an IP Packet. So far I used the function checksum published in the forum, I guess the result i should get is a cero (using header and checksum) but I get 29574. I manage to parse the packet in different variables to separate the header from the data, put them in a list and then make a new string of only data from header and checksum. Need to know what I'm doing wrong. Is the string I'm creating or how i'm using the string in the checksum function?

This is my code:

```
#Verifying if checksum of packet is correct
    str_header=''.join(str(header))
    print checksum(str_header)

#Reference:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1767910/checksum-udp-calculation-python
def carry_around_add(a, b):
    c = a + b
    return (c & 0xffff) + (c >> 16)

def checksum(msg):
    s = 0
    w = 0
    for i in range(0, len(msg), 2):
        w = ord(msg[i]) + (ord(msg[i+1]) << 8)
        s = carry_around_add(s, w)
    return ~s & 0xffff
```

The list header has this information:

```
Ver: 4
HL: 12
TOS: 0
LEN: 50
ID= 456
OFF: 16384
TTL: 5
PROT: 6
CHSUM: 12407
SRC: 16885952
DST: 167880896
rem_head: ['Q', 'Q', 'Q', 'Q', 'Q', 'Q', 'Q', 'Q', 'Q', 'Q', 'Q', 'Q', 'Q', 'Q', 'Q', 'Q', 'Q', 'Q', 'Q', 'Q', 'Q', 'Q', 'Q', 'Q', 'Q', 'Q', 'Q', 'Q']
data: ['A', 'A']
```

thanks

Comment: What might be helpful is posting the raw data (binary) that represents your header. That way anybody can write their own checksum algorithm and compare it to yours to see where you are going wrong.

Comment: Thank you fthinker for your reply. What do you mean with raw data? This is the data introduced in the fields in a packet generator program to create the packet written in a binary file.

Comment: What is `header`?  You're computing `''.join(str(header))`.  That's probably not what you want.

Comment: the header is the binary data I want to check, but I unpacked it first and create an string of it to make the checksum